# Using JNIEnv to instantiate/use objects

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

So I've implemented a ViewPager in Java that, for brevity, looks like this:

```
public class ViewpagerActivity extends ViewPager {
private Context _context;
public ViewpagerActivity(Context context) {
    super(context);
    _context = context;
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    ARViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ARViewPagerAdapter(_context, LayoutInflater.from(_context));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    addView(viewPager);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

In Monodroid I'm calling this (off the jar file) using the following:

```
        IntPtr _viewpagerview = Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FindClass("net/salespad/viewpager/ViewpagerActivity");
        IntPtr _viewpagerconstructor = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(_viewpagerview, "<init>", "(Landroid/context/Context;)V");
        IntPtr _viewpager = JNIEnv.NewObject(_viewpagerview, _viewpagerconstructor);
```

My question is- what do I do with the final IntPtr?  How do I cast that to a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instantiate a [Java.Lang.Object](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aJava.Lang.Object#) from the IntPtr like this:

```
var javaObject = new Java.Lang.Object(_viewpager, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
```

There is also the [JavaCast](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3aAndroid.Runtime.Extensions.JavaCast%60%601%28Android.Runtime.IJavaObject%29) extension method that can help you cast that object to another class:

```
var viewPager = javaObject.JavaCast<ViewPager>();
```

However, the problem you're going to run into here is that the ViewPager class isn't accessible from C#, meaning that logic will need to stay in Java for now.

Comment: I was worried I might have to do that.  Well, I guess I'll just have to port the compatibility libraries to get the functionality/reuse-ability I want :-D. Thanks.